# How can I convert a Binary file to a normal file and download it?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm lookin for a solution to convert my Binary file  (coming from my server) to a normal file and download it.
This is my server response :

```js
{
  "fileName": "1111.pdf",
  "binary" : "MyLongBInaryData" 
  }
```

The tricks here is : I don't know the type of file before download it, because it comes with response (1111.pdf, or myDoc.docx, etc..) so I want to be able to convert the binary data and download the specified file.
I've tried this :

```js
axios.get(`/MyBackendAPI`, {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/pdf',
        },
        })
        .then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
                new Blob([response.data])
                    );
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf'); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But It download a empty pdf, and I want to check for type of file before any download to be sure that I will download the correct format.
Any ideas please how to achieve this ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't know the type of the file? You just have said "it comes as 1111.pdf, or myDoc.docx, etc.. It seems you know the filetype from the filename because you receive the extension .pdf, .docx, etc..

Also, are you getting the binary of the data or you are getting the data encoded in base64 (for example), if that's the case, then you need to decoded before download the file.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I can know the file type in FileName axios response

Comment: I get the binary data, not base64

Comment: Did you try to use {type: "octet/stream"} in `new Blob([response.data], {type: "octet/stream"})` ?

Comment: Yes but I did'nt work, I think the problem is that I'm trying to convert all json response instead of just response.binary, but I don't know where to change it in my code haha^^'

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same. To use only the attribute "binary" you must change to:  `new Blob([response.data.binary], {type: "octet/stream"})`

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243452/discussion-between-brank-victoria-and-tania12).